# C macro: #if check for equality

Tags: c, macros, if-statement

Is there a way to do check for numerical equality in macros?

I want to do something like

```
#define choice 3

#if choice == 3
  ....
#endif

#if choice == 4
 ...
#endif
```

Does C macros have support for things like this?

Comment: What did your compiler tell you?

Comment: Better yet, what does the textbook / reference book say?

Comment: @Christoph My compiler is currently saying, "No, I don't support this." I'm trying to figure out why it's not working. So, your question is not helpful in my situation.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Indeed that should work.  See  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If

That reference is accurate, but written in "standards format":   abstractly without examples.

Answer (score 43):

Another way to write your code uses chained `#elif` directives:

```
#if choice == 3
  ...
#elif choice == 4
  ...
#else
  #error Unsupported choice setting
#endif
```

Note that if `choice` is not `#defined`, the compiler (preprocessor) treats it as having the value `0`.

Comment: How can we compare strings? Namely if I have a macro defined by `#define MY_MACRO Hello`. How can I make `if` to check its string value?

Comment: The ISO C preprocessor does not have a way to compare strings.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know that should work. What compiler are you using ?

PS : Just for information, the defines names are usually written in caps !

`#define CHOICE 3`