# C error directive defined behavior

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Working on preprocessor errors and warnings I discovered the following:

When using

```
#define TEST 4
#ifdef TEST
    #error "Wrong Test"
#endif
```

It will show the error during compilation, however using

```
#define TEST 4
#if (TEST==3)
    #error "Wrong Test"
#endif
```

Will still show the error, which is not expected. Changing `#error` directive with `#warning` it all works as expected.

Can somebody explain how to work around this problem since, in our compilation process we halt on errors and not on warnings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to both check a macro is defined and it equals a certain value at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160755/is-there-a-way-to-both-check-a-macro-is-defined-and-it-equals-a-certain-value-at)

Comment: What compiler are you using? This works correctly for me with gcc.

Comment: Anonymous my compiler is arm gcc 4.8.1. However I abstracted the test case and indeed this case is working but in my original file it does not seem to work. I will come back to this

Comment: Now I isolated the example everything works fine. Building it back in exposed the error. We use -D arguments for gcc to define the variable e.g. TEST. And in a other file this same variable is set when it is undefined. During the preprocessor phases the value changes from the value when undefined to -D define. It also looks like that #error and #warning directives run in different phases of the preprocessing. Summarized the problem is solved, thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> Now I isolated the example everything works fine. Building it back in exposed the error. We use -D arguments for gcc to define the variable e.g. TEST. And in a other file this same variable is set when it is undefined. During the preprocessor phases the value changes from the value when undefined to -D define. It also looks like that #error and #warning directives run in different phases of the preprocessing. Summarized the problem is solved, thanks for the comments!

Comment: ([Answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))