# -Wundef is not being ignored with pragma in g++

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings, clang++, pragma

Given the following code:

```
#if MACRO_WITHOUT_A_VALUE
int var;
#endif

int main(){}
```

When compiled with, `g++ -std=c++1z -Wundef -o main main.cpp`,
it produces the following warning:

```
main.cpp:1:5: warning: "MACRO_WITHOUT_A_VALUE" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #if MACRO_WITHOUT_A_VALUE
     ^
```

I'd like to keep the warning flag enabled, but suppress this particular instance.
I apply the following:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wundef"
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#endif

#if MACRO_WITHOUT_A_VALUE
int var;
#endif

#ifdef __GNUC__
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
#endif

int main(){}
```

This only solves the problem in `clang++`.

The command `clang++ -std=c++1z -Wundef -o main main.cpp` builds without warnings.
The command `g++ -std=c++1z -Wundef -o main main.cpp` builds with the same `[-Wundef]` warning as before.

**How can I suppress `-Wundef` warnings in `g++`?**

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~14.04.1) 5.1.0
clang version 3.8.0
```

Comment: Can you use `#if defined(MACRO_WITHOUT_A_VALUE) && MACRO_WITHOUT_A_VALUE`?

Comment: Perhaps, but I'm wrapping 3rd party code that I'd rather not modify.

Comment: Wrap it in `#ifdef` instead then?

Comment: @Ryan That's what I'm doing right now.  I was hoping I could have some kind of catch all without having to know the internal macros.  Something like:  `#include "push_all_warnings.hpp" #include "3rd_party.hpp" #include "pop_all_warnings.hpp"`

Comment: You have the `ignored` and `push` directives backwards, but it's otherwise a known GCC problem. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431

Comment: I can't tell from your question and the comments if this is for one specific instance or an entire third party header. If the former, wrap in `#ifdef`, in the latter case what I've done before is create my own `wrap_<header>.hpp` file that uses `#pragma GCC system_header` and then includes the third party header that induces warnings.

Comment: @MarkB That's exactly what I'm looking for.  `system_header` will work much better than me attempting to suppress every warning before including the 3rd party header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I've done before when third party headers were inducing warnings was to wrap them in my own private header that uses `#pragma GCC system_header` to just silence all the warnings from that header. I use my own wrapper to keep the includes neat and allow for an additional customization point in the future if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't disabling the warning, but fixing the preprocessor code to avoid it.
The below tests are based on a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48403396/1888983), using `clang -Weverything`...

```
#define ZERO 0
#define ONE 1
#define EMPTY

// warning: 'NOTDEFINED' is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
#if NOTDEFINED
#warning NOTDEFINED
#endif

// false
#if ZERO
#warning ZERO
#endif

// true
#if ONE
#warning ONE
#endif

// error: expected value in expression
#if EMPTY
#warning EMPTY
#endif

// false
#if defined(NOTDEFINED) && NOTDEFINED
#warning NOTDEFINED
#endif

// false
#if defined(ZERO) && ZERO
#warning ZERO
#endif

// true
#if defined(ONE) && ONE
#warning ONE
#endif

// error: expected value in expression
#if defined(EMPTY) && EMPTY
#warning EMPTY
#endif
```

The one liner `#if defined(SOME_MACRO) && SOME_MACRO` can avoid this warning. To explicitly handle the case...

```
#if defined(DEBUG_PRINT)
#if DEBUG_PRINT
... true
#else
... false
#endif
#else
#error DEBUG_PRINT must be defined
#endif
```

To handle `EMPTY` see this: [How to test if preprocessor symbol is #define'd but has no value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781520/how-to-test-if-preprocessor-symbol-is-defined-but-has-no-value)