# A way to check if preprocessor symbol is defined but empty?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

**Is there a way to check whether a preprocessor symbol is *defined but without value*?**

Consider the following bit of code:

```
#if defined( FOO )
  #if FOO == 1
    #error FOO defined to 1.
  #else
    #error FOO defined to other value than 1.
  #endif
#else
  #error FOO undefined
#endif

int main() {}
```

As is, this will give:

```
error: #error FOO undefined
```

If I add `#define FOO 1` to the top, I get:

```
error: #error FOO defined to 1.
```

So far, so good. **But** when I change that to `#define FOO` (i.e., *defining* `FOO`, but not defining it *to* something), I get:

```
error: operator '==' has no left operand
```

**Is there a way to check whether a preprocessor symbol is *defined but without value*?**

Comment: Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160755/is-there-a-way-to-both-check-a-macro-is-defined-and-it-equals-a-certain-value-at) question.